# Prevent click for Chocolat.js while dragging using slick.js

Tags: jquery, events, slick.js, chocolat.js

Right  now I have a draggable images container using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I want to preview full size when a single click happens using [Chocolat.js](http://chocolat.insipi.de/#demo),

The problem is that when I release the mouse (after dragg), still fires the full screen,

I tried to destroy the chocolat when the Dragg event begins, but it persists..

```
var $chocolat = $('.chocolat').Chocolat({
    imageSize: 'contain',
    loop: true
}).data('chocolat');

$('#bx-pager_builder').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    beforeChange: function() {
        $chocolat.api().destroy();
    },
    afterChange: function() {
        $chocolat = $('.chocolat').Chocolat({
            imageSize: 'contain',
            loop: true
        }).data('chocolat');
    }
});
```

The problem is that the Chocolat documentation doesn't provide examples..

Any idea if what i'm trying to do is posible? ( and how? ^^ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chocolat_images = [];
$('.chocolat .chocolat-image').each(function(i){
    chocolat_images[chocolat_images.length] = { src: $(this).find('img').attr('src')};
});
var $chocolat = $('.slick-slider.chocolat').Chocolat(
{
    imageSize: 'contain',
    loop: true,
    images: chocolat_images,
    imageSelector: ''
}).data('chocolat');

$('.chocolat').on('click', '.chocolat-image', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $chocolat.api().open($(this).index())
});
```

I was able to fix it like this. Handling 'manually' the event and the indexes

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a demo somewhere so I can understand the bug ?

Anyway this page, is full of examples, you can open it in your browser :
https://github.com/nicolas-t/Chocolat/blob/master/dist/index.html

These lines in particular :
https://github.com/nicolas-t/Chocolat/blob/master/dist/index.html#L142L240
show you how to use the API

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find this page! maybe you should consider including it in in the docs page :)